# Consolidation Method - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Dears,

I m facing a problem with Consolidation Method. I ' m receiving Run-time error 1004 on line:

```
.Consolidate Sources:=ArrSource, Function:=xlSum, _
   TopRow:=False, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
```

.Below is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test1()

    Dim ArrSource As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        ArrSource = .Range("A1:B20")

        With .Range("D1")
            .Consolidate Sources:=ArrSource, Function:=xlSum, _
                TopRow:=False, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: not 100%, but I think you need to pass in the range, not an array from it.

Comment: Use `.Range("A1:B20").Address(True, True, xlR1C1, False)` as `Sources`. It has to be R1C1 string address.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BrakNicku

Comment: Read more about R1C1 here: https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/cell-references-a1-r1c1-notation.htm